# How can I find the elevation a set distance upstream and downstream from a layer of crossing locations

Tags: qgis, hydrology

I have a channel network which I've intersected with a proposed road network to produce crossing locations. I need to find the channel slope averaged over a 20m stream length.

I also have a raster of elevations

Is there a way to 'look' upstream and downstream the channel network from a set of crossing locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In three steps:

(1) Create 20m line segments

Line segments +20/-20 meters from the crossing point is generated by 
**Service area (from layer)** tool (`Processing Toolbox | Network analysis`)

- Path type to calculate: Shortest
- Travel Cost: 20m

then **Multipart to singleparts** (`Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry`) to split upstream/downstream segments.

(2) Create Slope layer

Go to menu `Raster | Analysis | Slope`

(3) Calculate average of Slope value along the streams

Use **Add raster values to features** (in `SAGA | Vector <-> raster`) on `Slope` raster and `20m line` (i.e. `Single part` layer from the Step 1). It will automatically calculate average of the Slope along the stream.